# how to replace layer url with portalItem for offline Arcgis runtime sdk

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to gave offline access to my app. I am using ArcGis runtime 100 sdk. while implementing the same I found

```
//instantiate offline map task
    self.offlineMapTask = AGSOfflineMapTask(portalItem: self.portalItem)
```

this code of line to start with. But when i did some research then found that we can use LayerUrls in place of PortalItem.

How should i replace it with layer url

Comment: _"But when i did some research then found..."_ what code did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an Offline Map Task, you can pass in a Map or a Portal Item that points at a Web Map.

You can use Layer URLs when creating Feature Layers (e.g. to add to a Map's operational layers).

I think you may be conflating Web Maps with Feature Layers.

By the way, for future questions: you could consider asking in the [iOS Runtime SDK forum](https://community.esri.com/community/developers/native-app-developers/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-ios/content)?

Comment: thanks Nixta I'm really confused between feature layers and web maps. I will read the documention first